# make a function which calculate the number of same nearby character in flutter like aabcddaabb => 2abc2d2a2b

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

can anybody help me to build the function mentioned above I am using dart in the flutter and want this function
make a function which calculate the number of same nearby character in flutter like aabcddaabb => 2abc2d2a2b

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ... you see, you learn programming by ... programming yourself. It shouldn't be your first impulse to ask others to do the work for you. Study the material you got, get out, research some tutorials ... you can get so much information within minutes. Use the internet ... to LEARN how to do things. Not to get other people to do the learning for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a smarter and shorter way to do it, but here's a possible solution:

```
String string = 'aaabcddaabb';
String result = '';
String lastMatch = '';
int count = 0;
while (string.isNotEmpty) {
  if (string[0] != lastMatch) {
    result += '${count > 1 ? count : ''}$lastMatch';
    lastMatch = string[0];
    count = 0;
  }
  count++;
  string = string.substring(1);
}
result += '${count > 1 ? count : ''}$lastMatch';
print(result); //3abc2d2a2b
```

I also came up with this smarter solution. Even though it's nice that it's a single expression it's maybe not very readable:

```
String string = 'aaabcddaabb';
String result = string.split('').fold<String>(
    '',
    (r, e) => r.isNotEmpty && e == r[r.length - 1]
        ? r.length > 1 &&
                int.tryParse(r.substring(r.length - 2, r.length - 1)) != null
            ? '${r.substring(0, r.length - 2)}${int.parse(r.substring(r.length - 2, r.length - 1)) + 1}$e'
            : '${r.substring(0, r.length - 1)}2$e'
        : '$r$e');
print(result); //3abc2d2a2b
```

Answer (score 0):

Same

```dart
void main() {
  var input = 'aabcddaabb';
  print(getret(input));
}

String getret(String input) {
  var ret = '';
  var cc = '';
  var co = 0;
  
  cut(){
    var c = input[0];
    input = input.substring(1);
    return c;
  }
  
  write(){
    if(co == 1) ret = '$ret$cc';
    if(co > 1) ret = '$ret$co$cc';
  }
  
  while(input.isNotEmpty){
    final c = cut();
    if(c != cc){
      write();
      cc = c;
      co = 1;
    }else{
      co ++;
    }
  }
  
  write();
  
  return ret; // 2abc2d2a2b
}
```

[image]